# Выборка из N множеств по заданному критерию

Tags: алгоритм

Есть N множеств целых положительных чисел. Нужно найти количество таких комбинаций Ai элементов из каждого множества так, что выбранные элементы расходятся не более чем в C раз.

---

Чтобы было понятнее, давайте на конкретном примере. Пусть есть 2 множества:

```
{ 10, 15 }
{ 27, 19, 14 }
```

Необходимо подсчитать, сколькими способами мы можем выбрать **1 элемент** из первого множества и **2 элемента** из второго множества таким образом, чтобы все выбранные элементы расходились не более чем **в 2 раза**. В данном случае ответом будет:

```
{ 10, 19, 14 }
{ 15, 27, 19 }
{ 15, 27, 14 }
{ 15, 19, 14 } => 

Ответ: 4 варианта
```

Пробовал перебирать сочетания из N по K для каждого множества, группируя их и проверяя полученные множества на валидность, но выходит слишком долго, увы...

Comment: Вы говорите долго работает, а на каких данных?

Comment: @АндрейNOP До 6 множеств по 500 элементов

Comment: Раз уж вам нужно найти все возможные комбинации, удовлетворяющие условию, то от перебора никуда не уйти. Главное правильно реализовать отсечение, чтобы не перебирать лишнее

Comment: А выбирать элементов из этих 500 сколько нужно?

Comment: @АндрейNOP 1, 2, 3, ... 500 соответсвенно. Максимальное условие

Comment: Можно отсортировать каждый массив и при проходе просматривать его не полностью, а только тот кусочек, на котором выполняется наше условие кратности между min и max. Но в общем случае это мало что даст. Само по себе число сочетаний даже из 500 по 10 запредельно. А если его еще и в шестую степень возвести...